# hey, this guy has rep outside of SE. i think he should start with 101 points as was afforded to me when i started

Tags: discussion

Stefan Stenzel.  he's Mr. [Waldorf](http://www.waldorf-music.info/en/).

https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/25424/stefan-stenzel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robert, you got the +100 association bonus in Jan 2 '14 and the reason was that your dsp.stackexchange.com rep [got to 203 by a +10](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/4346/robert-bristow-johnson?tab=reputation&sort=time&page=13). This was 8 days before you joined any of the other sites, and more than half a year after Peter [recognized and greeted you](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8638/iir-filter-structure-implementation-dynamic-range/8640#8640) in dsp.stackexchange.com.

Soooooo, you don't need to be on any other sites to get the association bonus it seems, as long as you hit 200 rep.

Answer (score 1):

Well, his rep outside of Signal Processing is 1.

[image]

In order to qualify for the bonus 100 points, [you need to have at least 200 rep on the original site.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56506/award-account-association-bonus-automatically-upon-reaching-200-rep)

Comment: Peter, when i first appeared here, i had no nothing with any SE or with SO.  it was because you knew me from *comp.dsp*.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Erk.  Nothing that I've done or read would do that. I certainly don't know how to do it. Perhaps just gained rep quickly?!?!

Comment: well, Darth, i don't remember the dates, and i don't think i have the historical tools, but it was when i first appeared, i didn't need to earn my first 100 points.  and this was my first SE or SO.

Comment: Thanks for the sleuthing @OlliNiemitalo! :-)  You should add this as an answer.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson The bottom line is, to get that bonus the user needs to be active. Apart from registration with the sites, the user you point to has not been active --- and certainly not as active as you were / are.